# Why did Ashwin ask Reema about watching the movie "Ijazaat" in "Talvar"?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, talvar

Talking about the movie [Talvar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4934950/)

In the scene where Reema (played by Tabu) returned some items to Ashwin Kumar (played by Irfan Khan), Ashwin was upset. Coz those items (cards, letters, photos) were important to him and Reema mentioned them as "his stuff". Then after confirmation of trial separation between Reema & Ashwin, Ashwin said to Reema:

> Ashwin: Have you seen the movie "Ijazaat"
>
> Tabbu: No .... Why?
>
> Reema: Just asked ...

Then there was another scene where Reema called Ashwin, Ashwin heard a song and asked:

> Are you watching Ijazat ?

What's the significance of this movie "Ijazaat" that this was mentioned by the character in that context? I haven't seen Ijazaat. Does anyone know what Irfan was pointing at by mentioning this movie?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ijaazat

Comment: Reading the plot, I'm guessing Irfan meant he still loves her and Tabbu is making a mistake by leaving him. Not sure though if that was the intention of the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see that part again, you might hear Ashwin singing "Mera kuch Saman.." song which is written by Gulzar and is part of movie "Ijazat".

All though, they both have been in trial period of their divorce, Ashwin does not want to end his marriage. If you see the movie "Ijazat", It has same kind of story.

In the second conversation, When Reema call for her medicine mane, Ashwin hear the same song and that's why he asked her that was she watching the movie? It is just that both are still dependent on each other and even they separate they would be friends.

In the start when judge ask them why they want to divorce and Reema says there is nothing for what they stay together. But at the end of second conversation, they feel there is something still between them and that's why they are together at the end of the movie.